# C# and .NET 2.0: TcpListener.Pending() never sees incoming connection

Tags: c#, sockets, network-programming, .net-2.0, tcplistener

I am working on an application where I have no choice but to target .NET 2.0. This is a socket application using **TcpClient** and **TcpListener**, and I have opened the necessary ports in the Windows Firewall (Win 7.0.)  On one end, I use **TcpClient.Connect()** method to initiate a connection, and the **TcpListener.Pending()** method at the other end to detect the request.

The problem I am having is that **Pending()** never returns true at the server end.  I have checked to make sure the **Start()** method has been called, etc., and no errors are returned or exceptions thrown.  On the client end, I am using **Connect(), Write(), Flush(),** and **Close()** (which are all void return types) in a try/catch, and no exception occurs.  So, from the client's perspective, everything looks fine.  The problem is that the server never sees the connection request, so the data the client *thinks* it is sending never appears at the server.

Due to the extremely confidential nature of the work, I cannot post a source listing.  I am wondering if, from this description, someone can suggest some possible culprits.  As I said, I have opened the ports in the firewall - I was at first getting "*No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it*," but, after dealing with the firewall issues, all errors and exceptions went away, but still no data flows.

I know this is a tough one without source listings, but if you have seen this kind of problem before and can suggest places to look, I would much appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: How is Pending() written at server side? Is it inside a loop, or how and when are you accepting the client request?

Comment: It's always possible to add source code to a question. Break out the source into a new project and reproduce the problem there.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there is a "Whitelist" of sorts?  Maybe the server needs to "Whitelist" the client?